# How can I get the list of Work Items (Tasks) using Visual Studio Team Services (API) Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am getting started with Visual Studio Team Services, and I am trying to get the list of Work Items, I am searching in the documentation but I cant get what is the possible solution. Following Services I have already tested:
 https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyFirst/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=1.0

I can get a single work item using its ID but cant get all work items
 https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=4&api-version=1.0

Any help will be appreciable. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of work items you need to run a query.

https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/wiql

You can create your own or use one of the exciting ones. I tend to write them in the visual studio editor and then save it to the desktop and open in notepad.

Comment: Well, I think that [VSO REST API documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/work-items) is very very confusing. It also took me quite long to realize, that the first API endpoint on that page isn't actually a real endpoint.